# Access control and security: Should I have 1 massive ARTICLES table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, database-design

If you were making a system where USERS can write ARTICLES that cannot be seen nor accessed by other USERS, would you just have a single ARTICLES table with permissions controls?

I am not so sure having a single table with all the content in it is good for security. Yet, I don't think I want to make a new table containing the articles each USER.

Is there a better way to model this?

Comment: I wouldn't even consider anything other than a single article table, with access control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it is appropriate to make the database responsible for this sort of authorization check. The only "users" your database should be aware of are the applications allowed to access it. The business rules governing authenticating users and determining what those users are authorized to access belong within your application(s).

Instead look into existing authorization tools for managing access to your models. For example: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan